# Cant convert list's elements from string to float

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, csv, floating-point

```
import imagehash
from PIL import Image
import glob
import numpy as np
import csv

image_list = []
list_rows = []

for filename in glob.glob('/home/folder/*.jpg'):
    im = Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)
    img_hash = imagehash.average_hash(im)
    print(img_hash)
    list_rows.append([img_hash])

np.savetxt("numpy_test.csv", list_rows, delimiter=",", fmt='% s')

with open('numpy_test.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)

print(data)

print(type(data))

new_list = [float(i) for i in data]
print(new_list)
```

---

- Folder contains 3 images from which imagehashes are generated:

  ffffffffbfbfbfff

  ffffff7f7fffffff

  bf9fc7e3f1fdffff

  -Then these hashes are stored into a .csv file, which later i am reading it as a list.

  print(data) -> [['ffffffffbfbfbfff'], ['ffffff7f7fffffff'], ['bf9fc7e3f1fdffff']]

  print(type(data)) -> <class 'list'>

  new_list = [float(i) for i in data]

print(new_list) -> here i am trying to convert all the list's elements from string to float but the ERROR i keep getting is

```
new_list = [float(i) for i in data]
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

Answer (score 0):

each element of 'data' is stored as a list with a single string element inside it. If you instead used

```
new_list = [float(i[0]) for i in data]
```

you would be able to convert the strings.

Another way would be to alter how this list is created initially.